# Как преобразовать объект массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, highcharts, перебор

Необходимо изменить структуру из такой:

```
const data = [
    { name: "Product 0", feature1: 30, feature2: 51.6, year: 2015 },
    { name: "Product 1", feature1: 167.5, feature2: 59, year: 2016 },
    { name: "Product 2", feature1: 159.5, feature2: 49.2, year: 2015 }
];
```

в такую:

```
const newData = [
    { name: "Product 0", coordinates: [[30, 51.6]], year: 2015 },
    { name: "Product 1", coordinates: [[167.5, 59]], year: 2015 },
    { name: "Product 2", coordinates: [[159.5, 49.2]], year: 2015 }
];
```

Чтобы потом добавить в Highcharts.
Как это сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39235353/4928642

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, через цикл создавать объекты и кругами пихать их в новый пустой массив:

```
const data = [
    { name: "Product 0", feature1: 30, feature2: 51.6, year: 2015 },
    { name: "Product 1", feature1: 167.5, feature2: 59, year: 2016 },
    { name: "Product 2", feature1: 159.5, feature2: 49.2, year: 2015 }
];

let NewData = [];

for ( let i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ){
  let bubu = {};
  bubu.name = data[i].name;  
  bubu.coordinates = [[data[i].feature1,data[i].feature2]];
  bubu.year = data[i].year;
  NewData.push(bubu);
}
```

[JsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/wfhgjsmy/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
  { name: "Product 0", feature1: 30, feature2: 51.6, year: 2015 },
  { name: "Product 1", feature1: 167.5, feature2: 59, year: 2016 },
  { name: "Product 2", feature1: 159.5, feature2: 49.2, year: 2015 }
];

const newData = data.map(
  ({ name, feature1, feature2, year }) => ({ name, coordinates: [[feature1, feature2]], year })
); 

console.log(newData.map(o => JSON.stringify(o).replace(/,/g, ', ')).join('\n'));
```

---

```js
const data = [
  { name: "Product 0", feature1: 30, feature2: 51.6, year: 2015 },
  { name: "Product 1", feature1: 167.5, feature2: 59, feature3: 12.3, feature4: 45.6, year: 2016 },
  { name: "Product 2", feature1: 159.5, feature2: 49.2, year: 2015 }
];

const newData = data.map(
  ({ name, year, ...rest }) => ({ name, coordinates: [Object.values(rest)], year })
); 

console.log(newData.map(o => JSON.stringify(o).replace(/,/g, ', ')).join('\n'));
```